# Making SQL query more efficient

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

How can I make this SQL query more efficient?

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE price < 10) AS priceUnder10,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE price BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AS price10to20,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE price > 20) AS priceOver20,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE colour = 'Red') AS colourRed,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE colour = 'Green') AS colourGreen,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE colour = 'Blue') AS colourBlue;
```

I already have indexes on the `price` and `colour` columns, so I am looking for a better way to aggregate the data.

I have looked into using `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, self-joins and window functions, but cannot work out how to achieve the same result.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN 1 END) AS priceUnder10,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 1 END) AS price10to20,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN price> 20 THEN 1 END) AS priceOver20,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN colour = 'Red' THEN 1 END) AS colourRed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN colour = 'Green' THEN 1 END) AS colourGreen,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN colour = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) AS colourBlue
from YourTable  
WHERE price IS NOT NULL OR  colour IN ('Red','Green','Blue' )
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, but why is the `WHERE` necessary?

Comment: @gjb -It might well not be but imagine that you have a 1,000,000 row table and only 1 row has a non null price or colour in `'Red','Green','Blue'` The other 999,999 rows will make no difference to the result but still be scanned without it. Of course you may well know that your data doesn't have this distribution (`price` might not even be nullable) and it might as well be removed!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your database handles boolean expressions, this:

```
select sum(price<10),sum(price between 10 and 20)...  from tab;
```

or this

```
select sum(case when price<10 then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when price between 10 and 20 then 1 else 0 end)...  from tab;
```

might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as products, 

if(price < 10, 'price band 1',
 if (price between 10 and 20, 'price band 2',
  'price band 3'
 )
) as priceband,
  t.colour

from table t
group by t.colour, pricebrand
```

That will give you

```
products    colour    priceband
53          red       price band 1
65          red       price band 2
12          blue      price band 1
23          blue      price band 2
```

etc.

Comment: This nests the results, which isn't quite what I was looking for. Still, useful to know, so thanks.